# Page looks fine on Chrome and other browsers, but on Internet Explorer its added loads of space inbetween my images?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

not sure whats going on here. I didn't even notice the compatibility issue until someone pointed out. The images are positioned fine on Chrome and other browsers, but on Internet Explorer after the first two images there seems to be an incredible amount of white space before the next two?

I'd like to know how resolve this so I can avoid it in the future, so theory on why its doing it and how your fix fixes it along with an answer would be brilliant. Here to learn, not just get quick answers!

Album with screenshot of what the page looks like on IE, and what it looks like on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVoxY.jpg

HTML & CSS:

```
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-1.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-2.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none; src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-3.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-4.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-5.jpg" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to apply css reset?

Comment: This should be closed as offtopic > tipographycal error

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know it was as simple as a syntax error! Its that time of the week, Friday! Delete the question if you want.

Comment: I have marked Ray Hogan's answer as the correct answer as he noticed it first.

Comment: No deletion, only closing. As you can see in my comment, typographical errors are offtopic in stackoverflow. Try to reproduce the issue isolated and maybe you'll notice the typo before post a question. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third image tag isn't correct. You're missing the closing " on the style attribute, which is causing the src attribute to not being picked up. Replace the code with this:

```
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-1.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-2.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-3.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-4.jpg" />
<img style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" src="/sites/all/themes/br/assets/images/LNS-media-pack_survey-results-5.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing that the browser is converting a line of code incorrectly:

```
<img 
style="width: 45%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none; 
src=" lns-media-pack_survey-results-3.jpg"="" images="" assets="" br="" themes="" all="" sites="">
```

There is

no terminating " for the style
a space in src="_lns ....

Answer (score 1):

On the third image you forget to close your style attribute

```
..float: none; src="..
```

You need to

```
..float: none;" src="..
```

I do not know if it's the fault